# VB.Net 2013 Excel workbook object created by class limits properties / methods

Tags: vb.net, excel

The intention of my code is to use a class cWB to open workbooks and return a full-function Workbook object. 
My problem is that the oBook object created and returned by my class, does not give me access to the 
full property/method set of an Excel.Workbook. 
For example using oBook.Sheets gives the Intellisense message: 'Error: 'Sheets' is not a member of cWB
Any suggestions appreciated.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class cWB
    Public Property IsOpen As Boolean
    Public Property oBook As Excel.Workbook

    Sub New(ByVal xlApp As Excel.Application, ByVal filename As String)

        Try
            Me.oBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filename, ReadOnly:=True)
            Me.IsOpen = True
            Me.oBook = oBook
            Exit Sub

        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.IsOpen = False
            Me.oBook = Nothing
        End Try

    End Sub

    Sub Close()
        Me.oBook.Close()
        Me.oBook = Nothing
    End Sub
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Module Module1

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim filename As String = "D:\workbook.xls"
        Dim oBook As New cWB(xlApp, filename)

        Try
            If oBook.IsOpen = True Then
                Console.WriteLine("oBook.oBook=" & oBook.oBook.Name _
                                  & " now open=" & oBook.IsOpen)

                'Error: 'Sheets' is not a member of cWB
                'Console.WriteLine(oBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value())

            Else
                Console.WriteLine("oBook.oBook=" & oBook.oBook.Name _
                                  & " now open=" & oBook.IsOpen)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up")
        oBook.Close()
        Console.ReadLine()

        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(oBook)
    End Sub
```

Output:

```
oBook.oBook=workbook.xls now open=True
Cleaning up
```

Comment: `oBook.oBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value()` - `Sheets` is not a direct member of your oBook instance of `cWB`, but of its property `oBook` (which is a super-confusing way to name things BTW).

Comment: Yes I could name the property that contains the opened worbook object oBook.pBook

Comment: The problem would remain, right?

Comment: Are saying that second oBook in oBook.oBook is the full function workbook object?

Comment: Yes - the first `oBook` in your code is the instance of `cWB`, which is your custom class, and not an instance of `Workbook`

Comment: Thank you for you help. I now understand. Question answered.